# Integrating Discogs disconnect node module in Aurelia project

Tags: npm, aurelia, disconnect, discogs-api

I'm using aurelia.io, and I'd like to use "disconnect" npm package in my app to handle Discogs API.
I install it normally, typing `npm install disconnect --save` in the folder of my app.
I also edit `aurelia.json` correctly to insert in the `vendor-bundle.js` section :

          `{
            "name": "disconnect",
            "path": "../node_modules/disconnect",
            "main": "index"
          },`

Then I buikd my app typing `au build`, but I get this error:

```
{ uid: 8,
  name: 'writeBundles',
  branch: false,
  error: 
   { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/disconnect/lib/util.js'
       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:558:18)
       at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:468:33)
       at Object.exports.readFileSync (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/file-system.js:49:13)
       at fileRead (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/bundled-source.js:83:31)
       at Object.context.fileRead (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:176:18)
       at Object.context.load (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:357:30)
       at Module.load (eval at <anonymous> (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:832:29)
       at Module.fetch (eval at <anonymous> (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:822:66)
       at Module.check (eval at <anonymous> (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:854:30)
       at Module.enable (eval at <anonymous> (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:1173:22)
     errno: -2,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'open',
     path: '/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/disconnect/lib/util.js',
     moduleTree: [ 'disconnect/index' ],
     fileName: '/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/disconnect/index.js' },
  duration: [ 4, 789092986 ],
  time: 1490043332523 }
{ uid: 0,
  name: '<series>',
  branch: true,
  error: 
   { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/disconnect/lib/util.js'
       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:558:18)
       at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:468:33)
       at Object.exports.readFileSync (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/file-system.js:49:13)
       at fileRead (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/bundled-source.js:83:31)
       at Object.context.fileRead (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:176:18)
       at Object.context.load (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:357:30)
       at Module.load (eval at <anonymous> (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:832:29)
       at Module.fetch (eval at <anonymous> (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:822:66)
       at Module.check (eval at <anonymous> (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:854:30)
       at Module.enable (eval at <anonymous> (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:1173:22)
     errno: -2,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'open',
     path: '/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/disconnect/lib/util.js',
     moduleTree: [ 'disconnect/index' ],
     fileName: '/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/disconnect/index.js' },
  duration: [ 8, 704096699 ],
  time: 1490043332559 }
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/disconnect/lib/util.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:558:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:468:33)
    at Object.exports.readFileSync (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/file-system.js:49:13)
    at fileRead (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/bundled-source.js:83:31)
    at Object.context.fileRead (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:176:18)
    at Object.context.load (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:357:30)
    at Module.load (eval at <anonymous> (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:832:29)
    at Module.fetch (eval at <anonymous> (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:822:66)
    at Module.check (eval at <anonymous> (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:854:30)
    at Module.enable (eval at <anonymous> (/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:1173:22)
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/disconnect/lib/util.js',
  moduleTree: [ 'disconnect/index' ],
  fileName: '/home/cesar/projets/aurelia/tracklist-manager/node_modules/disconnect/index.js' }
```

I don't know what's wrong...
If you can help me, it would be great :)

Comment: The package you are installing is a Node package, it's not meant for use in the browser.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. I didn't know there was a difference. How can I distinguish packages meant for browsers from others? Thanks.

Comment: Usually you can determine this by reading the description of the package on it's NPM page or it's GitHub page. It'll mention Node if it's for use in Node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/disconnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was mentioned in the answer of the Ashley, my problem is irresolvable the way I wanted.
Some node packages are only made for servers and not browsers...